Issues with TLS Handshake Failure Using mkcert SSL Certificates in Python aioquic WebTransport Server
I've generated SSL certificates using mkcert and can successfully access them via HTTPS using Chrome. However, when I use the same SSL certificates with my Python aioquic WebTransport server, Chrome throws the following error: TLS handshake failure (ENCRYPTION_HANDSHAKE) 46: certificate unknown.
Here are the steps I followed:
1.Generated the SSL certificates using mkcert.
2.Successfully accessed a webpage over HTTPS using these certificates in Chrome.
3.Implemented a WebTransport server using Python's aioquic library.
4.Attempted to access the WebTransport server in Chrome, which resulted in the TLS handshake failure error.
How can I resolve the TLS handshake failure (ENCRYPTION_HANDSHAKE) 46: certificate unknown error when using mkcert SSL certificates with a Python aioquic WebTransport server?
Is there a way to disable SSL certificate validation for WebTransport in Chrome, or any workaround to make Chrome accept these certificates?
